# Compiler can't deduce template parameter in basic function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function, whose type depends on type parameters. The compiler can't deduce template parameter even if it's obvious. This is a basic code and even here it doesn't know it is an `int` (`int` is just example). What should be changed to make it work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 pr (T2 w) {
    return int(w);
}

int main() {
cout<<pr('A');  // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Null: I rejected your edit - _type parameters_ is the correct name for `T1` and `T2`. Template parameters can be either _type parameters_, _non-type parameters_ or _template template parameters_.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler can only deduce template type arguments only from function arguments types, not from result type. To make it work without changing function template you need to explicitly specify type argument:

```
cout << pr<int>('A');
```

But it is probably better to change the definition, since `T1` parameter doesn't seem to be useful:

```
template<class T>
int pr (T w){
    return int(w);
}
```

In C++11 you can use trailing return type, which might be useful in more complex situations:

```
template<class T>
auto pr (T w) -> decltype(int(w)) {
    return int(w);
}
```

And finally C++14 has return type deduction, so ther it is simply:

```
template<class T>
auto pr (T w) {
```

Comment: As I said int is just an example. The problem is that T1 is new type depend on T2 and i don't know T2 when i call pr(). So is there any way to do it without using <int> in c++11?

Comment: @MikeScamp. In C++11 you can use decltype, so it shouldn't be much of a problem; you only need to repeat the returned expression in decltype (see my example). In C++98 that would be more difficult. You would need to derive type separately. Probably using specialized class templates like.